# Which design pattern I should use for alfresco web service clients

Tags: vaadin, alfresco

I am creating a file manager application using vaadin as ui and alfresco as file storage. I am using alfresco web service client to communicate with alfresco.

Can anyone suggest me which design pattern I should use to call alfresco web service clients?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't have to force your self using design patterns. Design patterns are reusable solutions to certain problems. I see no problem with calling web services directly. Just make your code clean, remove duplication and develop some simple internal API for making the calls.

Second. There are some content management integration patterns you could use. But you have to be more specific on what you are doing. If it is a simple file broswer you could use "browser view" pattern but not necesary.

I wouldn't complicate things too much if it is just a simple application though.

The other thing you didn't tell us is what kind of web services are you using? RESTful or SOAP?

Hope this helps a bit. :)

Comment: Thanks Matjaz, I am using RESTful web services.

Answer (score 0):

There's no design pattern that only addresses web services calls. If you really look for patterns to help you design the integration, you might want to look at [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/toc.html).

Prerequisite is that you have a thorough understanding of the integration constraints, such as sync vs async, sequentiality, failure handling and propagation, etc.

Other patterns I found intriguing are the ones from [Nygard](http://www.michaelnygard.com/)'s excellent book [Release it!](http://pragprog.com/book/mnee/release-it), such as [Circuit Breaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern), Timeout and Bulkhead.